# Bash script can't find file in relative path directory

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to bash and I am trying to create a script that should find an archive in a given directory. `$1` is the name of archive.

When the given path is `./1/ar.tgz` the script works. But when path is `../data 1/01_text.tgz` I have the following problem:

> dirname: extra operand "1/01_text.tgz"

and then `No such file or directory`.

Here is my code fragment:

```
VAR=$1
DIR=$(dirname ${VAR})
cd $DIR
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ahmed's answer is right, but you also need to enclose `VAR` in double quotes. The correct code fragment is:

```
VAR=$1
DIR=$(dirname "$VAR")
cd "$DIR"
```

Answer (score 1):

The space is causing the problem: `cd $DIR` gets expanded to `cd ../data 1/01_text.tgz` and `cd` doesn't know what to make of the third "argument". Add quotes around the directory: `cd "$DIR"`.